# How to find out if element is in any dictionary for specific key in list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary

```
listofdict = [{'name':"John",'surname':"Adelo",'age':15,'adress':"1st Street 45"},{'name':"Adelo",'surname':"John",'age':25,'adress':"2nd Street 677"},...]
```

I want to check if there is anyone with the name John in dictionary and if there is: True, if not: False. Here is my code:

```
def search(name, listofdict):
    a = None
    for d in listofdict:
        if d["name"]==name:
            a = True
        else:
            a = False
    print a
```

However this doesn't work. If name=John it returns False, but for name=Adelo it return True. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python supplies logic that helps avoids all the complications of loops.  For example:

```
def search(name, listofdict):
    return any( d["name"]==name for d in listofdict )
```

Comment: Sorry, I see this is a generator solution.

Comment: I mean, I like your answer, but it does not tell him what is wrong in his code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `break` right after `a = True`.

Otherwise, `a` is always False when the target key is not in the **last** dictionary in `listofdict`.

By the way, this is cleaner:

```
def search(name, listofdict):
    for d in listofdict:
        if d["name"]==name:
            return True
    return False
```